# How to disable remote debugging in CefSharp?

Tags: c#, chromium, cefsharp

I'm trying to add Chromium control to my WebForms C# app uing CefSharp. It works okay, but I can't log in to Google account via this control. Google login page says:

> The browser is not secure, try another one.

On the support page they say:

> This may happen because the Chromium browser has remote debugging mode enabled.

How can I overcome the problem and make Chromium instance looking trustworthy to Google?

Comment: Remote debugging is disabled by default.  Google is blocking logins from all chromium embedded framework based browsers see https://security.googleblog.com/2019/04/better-protection-against-man-in-middle.html?m=1